# Dash meaning in access between if statement and converting it to PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, ms-access

I have a query that I got out of an access database that I'm trying to write in postgreSQL.
I'm having trouble translating this line `iif(isNull(table2.salaried), 0, table2.salaried) - iif(isNull(table1.paymet_due), 0, table1.paymet_due) AS salary_due` into PostgreSQL. The first thing I'm confused about is the `-` in the query. What does this mean? How can I convert this line into PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         table1."customer_id",
         iif(isNull(table2.salaried), 0, table2.salaried) - iif(isNull(table1.paymet_due), 0, table1.paymet_due) AS salary_due 
       --coalesce(table1.paymet_due, 0) AS salary_due

      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               tbl_archive."customer_id",
               SUM(tbl_sent."grand_total_paymet_due") AS paymet_due 
            FROM
               tbl_sent 
               LEFT JOIN
                  tbl_archive 
                  ON tbl_sent."npi" = tbl_archive."cust_badge_numb" 
         )
         AS table1 
         LEFT JOIN
            (
               SELECT
                  tbl_archive."customer_id",
                  SUM(wage."Amount") AS salaried 
               FROM
                  wage 
                  LEFT JOIN
                     tbl_archive 
                     ON wage."sum_amount" = tbl_archive."cust_badge_numb" 
            )
            AS table2 
            ON table1."customer_id" = table2."customer_id"
   )
   AS tbl_salaried
```

Comment: Are `salaried` and `paymet_due` numeric values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple subtraction:

- Value A is 0 if `table2.salaried` is NULL, otherwise it is `table2.salaried`.
- Value B is 0 if `table1.paymetdue` is NULL, otherwise it is `table1.paymetdue`.

And the value shown in the query is value A minus value B.

So the proper translation would be

```
coalesce(table2.salaried, 0) - coalesce(table1.paymet_due, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` function which returns the first non null argument.

For example:

```
coalesce(field1,field2,0) - will return field 1 unless it's null. If field1 is null, it will return field2 unless it's null. If both field1 and field2 are null, it will return 0.
```

In your case, you can use: `coalesce(table2.salaried, 0)` instead of `iif(isNull(table2.salaried), 0, table2.salaried)`

Regarding the `-`, it really depends whether the fields are numeric or dates.

- For numeric - you can leave the `-` as is.
- For dates - you have to know what specifically you want to extract - number of days/months/etc between the dates...